# Adding Chart Guide using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, chart

I wish to add a guide to the Bar chart in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy but I couldn't find anything in documentation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done via the CIM module. See the [Cartographic Information Model](https://github.com/esri/cim-spec).
You want to work down from [CIMCharts](https://github.com/Esri/cim-spec/blob/main/docs/v3/CIMCharts.md).axes -> CIMChartAxis.guides -> [CIMChartGuide](https://github.com/Esri/cim-spec/blob/main/docs/v3/CIMCharts.md#cimchartguide)